# Webapi protecting with certificate authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have web api application which is deployed in azure app service and hybrid mobile consuming those services.Now I want to implement authentication using certificate.Can anyone help me how to do this.

Comment: You can have a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2016/05/02/using-client-certificate-authentication-for-web-api-hosted-in-azure/ and http://www.razibinrais.com/secure-web-api-with-client-certificate/. Hope it will be helpful!

Comment: @Hannahwy, Thanks for quick reply. As of now i follwed the following steps. Just let me either approch is correct or not if you have any idea about this. Thanks in advance.1)We have generated certificate from local machine

2)Then uploaded as ApIManagement service in azure and it given thumbprint

3)Overriden the authrization filterattribute to validate certifcate and we are passing encrypted thumbprint from mobile app

Comment: Per my understanding, you can transfer your API application to API Management. And then refer to the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates to upload a client certificate. API Management helps you authenticate the client certificate. Your mobile app just needs to call the API Management. But you need to pay extra for API Management.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known, to set up your web app to require client certificates, you need to add the clientCertEnabled site setting for your web app and set it to true. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth).

Comment: Where we have to generate certificate in azure or local. Actually I have generated certificate in windows machine and uploaded certificate in apimanagementservice in azure.

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to configure certificate authentication for Azure API management service. If so, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates